# How to encode and decode query string from javascript to servletpage using java?

Tags: javascript, java, querystringparameter

How to encode and decode query string from javascript to servletpage

### Javascript

```
var page=http://localhost/jsp/index.jsp?pname=jack & sparrow&price=$20&rate=10 - 20%

$('#listContent').load(page);
```

I got 404 error

```
var page=http://localhost/jsp/index.jsp?pname=titanic&price=10&rate=12

$('#listContent').load(page);
```

this one working fine

how to pass if query string contain space and special symbols

how to encode it and how to pass this query string

if it is encoded how to decode in servlet page

My expected output as
    String pname=request.getParameter("pname")
    String price=request.getParameter("price")
    String rate=request.getParameter("rate")

```
pname=jack & sparrow
price=$20
rate=10 - 20%
```

Comment: `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @vlaz how to use it in java script

Answer (score 0):

On the Javascript side you have to encode it using function `encodeURIComponent(yourString)`

If you want to decode such string on Java side, you can do it using (for example) `new java.net.URI(receivedString).getPath()`

Comment: var page=encodeURIComponent(http://localhost/jsp/index.jsp?pname=jack & sparrow&price=$20&rate=10 - 20%);

 $('#listContent').load(page);

 String pname=request.getParameter("pname").toString

 Can i get this pname as - jack & sparrow

Comment: Give me a correct output you see my query string has multiple parameters i want each parameter by paarmeter